# Building 2 projects inside 1 project

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

Is it doable to do 2 projects in 1 project?

Basically what I want to do is to build an `api server` and a `static server`, that uses shared `.cljc` code.

If this is doable, how to manage it's dependencies, repl and how to jar it up such that if I want to jar the `api server`-part I don't need to include the `static server`-part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use lein then you could use lien plugin. Here is link https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-sub